# How to form loop inside loop that reflects jumpings in the pattern to create a certain pattern that is given below?

Tags: r, loops, mode

When I work on pairwise conditional and partial Granger causality, I decided to express the effect receivings of each of the variables in a given system via a simple function. Here, "pairwise" is in the sense of advanced G-causality theory; namely, the number of independent (causer) variables and the number of dependent variables are BOTH 1 when they are conditioned on third set of variables (possibly with more than 1 variables). Note that in advanced GC theory, counfounding effects are taken into account, and those effects are subtracted from the main effect, hence, a clear effect in one direction is found, i.e., isolated from the effects of confounding variables; hence, that is true causality.

Now, to reflect the effect receiving matrix (5x6), first, the effects matrix is considered:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 (Variables)
1  6  11 16 21 26
2  7  12 17 22 27
3  8  13 18 23 28
4  9  14 19 24 29
5  10 15 20 25 30
```

Each of the cells from 1 to 30 holds a p value (I did not enter exact p values themselves; rather entered location index for each p value). It is read like this:

(The effect of a variable on itself is disregarded: every variable is the cause of itself!)

The GC from V1 to V2 conditional on the others (V3,V4,V5,V6) is 1. Hence, V2 is receiving an effect of 1.

The GC from V1 to V3 conditional on the others (V2,V4,V5,V6) is 2. Hence, V3 is receiving an effect of 2.

The GC from V1 to V4 conditional on the others (V2,V3,V5,V6) is 3. Hence, V4 is receiving an effect of 3.
...
The GC from V5 to V4 conditional on the others (V1,V2,V3,V6) is 24. Hence, V4 is receiving an effect of 24.
...
The GC from V2 to V1 conditional on the others (V3,V4,V5,V6) is 6. Hence, V1 is receiving an effect of 6.

This way, the value of effect receivings are derived. I want to embed these effect receiving values to a 6x5 matrix (here, 6 is for variables):

Effect Receiving Matrix (6x5):

```
Vars
V1 6  11 16 21 26
V2 1  12 17 22 27
V3 2   7 18 23 28
V4 3   8 13 24 29
V5 4   9 14 19 30
V6 5  10 15 20 25
```

I want to create a matrix with above entries: i.e., a[1,1]=6  a[1,2]=11  a[2,3]=17...

**What I tried:**
I tried loop inside loop, thought mode operations can be helpful. Anyway, I did not solve.
**What I observed:**
**1.** There is a pattern: increase 5*k
**2.** This pattern is damaged at jumps. For example, for V1, there is a jump at i=1; for V2, there is a jump at i=2; for V6, there is no jump since up to that jumping point, V6's all effect receivings are recorded.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wrote the question very clearly with its root. i.e. from where the need was arosed. Possibly, the "down" vote is due to the lengthy detail. Anyway, I attach great importance to the connection btw. questions and their theoretical roots.

Comment: I don't understand how the values of GC are calculated. Can you give us a formula?

Comment: The values 1 to 30 holds INDICES of the related p values; not the p values themselves, of course. p values are btw. 0 and 1, naturally. The exact values of p depends on the data set we use; and not important for the question here. By adding 5 p values I obtain total effect receivings of a variable. I do that for all the variables. I also considered "effecting the others" as well as "effect receivings". Hence, in a VAR, W=f(Wt-1, Wt-2,...), I consider a structure F(G)=0, and therefore "effecting the others" and "effect receivings"; hence, decide upon the order of variables from more exo to endo

Comment: The calculation methodology of (cond'l and part'l) GC values are so theoretical: 1. Roelstraete, Rosseel; "FIAR: An R Package for Analyzing Functional Integration in the Brain", JSS, Vol. 44, Issue 13, Oct 2011. 2. Cevher, "Causfinder: An R package for Systemwise Analysis of Conditional and Partial Granger Causalities", International Journal of Science and Advanced Technology, October 2014. http://www.ijsat.com/view.php?id=2014:October:Volume%204%20Issue%2010 Anyway, the Question here is totally independent from that theory. Obtain the 2nd matrix from the 1st one. That is all.

Comment: @Lustrik, The reading of GC is from the columns to the rows. This is standard everywhere: In Matlab: MVGC, GCCA, GrangerCausalityGUI packages. In R: causfinder package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us dispense with the high-powered jargon like Granger Causality, and just call it effect.

Isn't it more expressive in terms of following expression?

```
vars <- 1:6
id <- c()
for (i in 1:6){
  id <- c(id, vars[-i])
}
df1 <- stack(df)
df1$id <- id
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, ind, values)
#  id  1  2  3  4  5  6
#1  1 NA  6 11 16 21 26
#2  2  1 NA 12 17 22 27
#3  3  2  7 NA 18 23 28
#4  4  3  8 13 NA 24 29
#5  5  4  9 14 19 NA 30
#6  6  5 10 15 20 25 NA
spread(df1, id, values)
#  ind  1  2  3  4  5  6
#1   1 NA  1  2  3  4  5
#2   2  6 NA  7  8  9 10
#3   3 11 12 NA 13 14 15
#4   4 16 17 18 NA 19 20
#5   5 21 22 23 24 NA 25
#6   6 26 27 28 29 30 NA
```

It easily reads, for instance, the effect of 1 to 2 is `1`, 2 to 1 is `6`, 5 to 6 is `25` etc.

**Input used**

```
df <- structure(list(`1` = 1:5, `2` = 6:10, `3` = 11:15, `4` = 16:20, 
    `5` = 21:25, `6` = 26:30), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I run your code; the result of the spread is rowwise, not columnwise in my results: e.g. "NA  6 11 16 21 26" is the 1st row in my result; it is 1st column in your result! Similarly, for the others: Your columns are my rows. Could you please look it there a little?